# New to HP Switching. Asking topology questions

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, stacking, php

I have following design:
[image]

When I learn switching i started learning on cisco switches. Now We have 3 hp switches. We have to configure spanning tree between sw1,sw2 and sw3.

All I did was type spanning-tree in cli and change priority so that sw1 is root switch.

But I have another requirement, I want to access those three switches (i.e SW1,SW2 and SW3) from SW4. I am assuming I have to stack it?

Also, we use trunk mode between switches in cisco, do I have to do that in HP Switches?

Comment: You do not have to make any changes for sw4 to work.

Comment: so basically it will work like plug in play? @RonTrunk

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean exactly by "I want to access 1, 2 and 3 from sw4."  If you want to log in to sw4's CLI and directly manipulate the other switches, then yes, you should stack them.  If you want traffic to be switched onto the first three switches from a device connected to sw4 then that should already be working in the default config.

Trunk in Cisco means something completely different than trunk in HP.  Cisco's trunk is an interface that carries multiple tagged VLANs.  In HP, a trunk is a group of interfaces aggregated into a single logical trunk group.  In other words, LAG or link aggregation.  The whole thing is really confusing.

At any rate, if you need to create something on an HP device which is analogous to Cisco's "trunk" you'll need to use what HP simply refers to as "tagged port" configuration within the VLAN context.

Comment: Right so basically if i wanna do spanning tree on three switches:
all i do is "spanning-tree" command and change priority to make desired switch as root switch. Correct? @Tedwin

Comment: Please read this HP STP guide and if you have specific questions I will happy to try to help.  http://www.hp.com/rnd/support/manuals/pdf/release_06628_07110/Bk2_Ch5_STP.pdf